# Can't find view in android

Tags: android

I am trying to develop a filter using following ways. I can not find red highlighted **View in android**. How can I achieve this.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Red highlighted view? You mean a border? Just use a relative layout and make it red then inside this relative layout place another relative layout and your views go in there?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Skynet I just highlight particular area using RED line for understanding purpose

Comment: @maveň just let me know if there is any inbuilt view available in android or should I develop it manually?

Comment: what do you mean by "I can find red highlighted View in android" , are you want to know how to design it?

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat no I just want to know if there is available any inbuilt View or should I develop it manually?

Comment: as a design or as functionality?

Comment: design only but only one tab is activated in each view.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="78dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="#CCDEF6" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/delete"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="05dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/icn_edit_45x45"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/edit"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/delete"
                    android:background="@drawable/icn_delete_45x45"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You got me wrong I am trying to develop View in side Red Square.

Comment: Please check the above it has your square in blue and it has the views inside!! These views have @+id/delete and @+id/edit as ID

Comment: I want clickable tab like AC Non AC etc

Comment: Check the layout mate, your clicks will not be hindered! Or maybe I am not getting your question here - pardon me for that

Answer (score 0):

1. Make this xml in your drawable :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dip"
        android:color="#007f00" />

</shape>
```

2. After making this set it background to your bustype below layout.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement any custom view.

1) First include that AC-NON_AC layout to a relative layout with padding eg.5dp .

2) Then set background of relative layout #FF0000 i.e. Red color.

If any problem persists , ask me .I will help you.